# Waiting for flutter command to release the startup lock

Tags: flutter, release, flutter-doctor, lockfile

I am unable to run "flutter pub get" or "flutter doctor" because it always tells me to wait for another flutter command to release the startup lock and then exits with code 69.

List of solutions I tried:

- killall -9 dart -> gets "No matching processes belonging to you were found FAIL: 1"
- Removing /bin/cache/lockfile: I delete it and then it appears again after I try to launch flutter doctor
- delete the directory & restart my Mac & download again -> same errors
- Tried to remove the flock check in _lock function in bin/internal/shared.sh like this

function _lock () {
if hash shlock 2>/dev/null; then
shlock -f "$1" -p $$
else
mkdir "$1" 2>/dev/null
fi
}
and no results....

Comment: please reset you system and try again

Comment: What do you mean by reset the system?